# How to load a ResourceDictionary by culture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization

Any other approach than the one I am suggesting here is welcome.

I have a project where I'm trying to manage localization using XAML resource dictionaries. In order to avoid having to implement localization loading on all my code-behing files, I have written the following converter:

```
public class LocalizationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string filePrefix = value as string;

        string language;

        // Filter so only supported languages are let through
        switch (culture.Name.Substring(0, 2))
        {
            case "da":
                language = "da";
                break;

            default:
                language = "en";
                break;
        }

        return filePrefix + "." + language + ".xaml";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I write the XAML to load the language dictionary, giving the file prefix as value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I ended up using a static method to load my localization instead. Here's the method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads localization based on culture.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dictionary">The dictionary to load localization to</param>
/// <param name="basePath">The base path of the localization files. See remarks for further info.</param>
/// <param name="cultureInfo">Culture to load localization for.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// The loaded localization file will be <code>basenameLocalization.languagecode.xaml</code>
/// (e.g. <code>MainWindowLocalization.de.xaml</code>), or <code>basenameLocalization.languagecode.xaml</code>
/// for the default localization.
/// </remarks>
internal static void ReplaceLocalization(
    ResourceDictionary dictionary,
    string basePath,
    CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();

    // Clean out old localization
    ResourceDictionary oldLocalization = null;
    foreach (ResourceDictionary d in dictionary.MergedDictionaries)
    {
        if (d.Source.OriginalString.StartsWith(basePath + "Localization."))
        {
            oldLocalization = d;
        }
    }
    if (oldLocalization != null)
    {
        dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Remove(oldLocalization);
    }

    // Get thee language
    string language = "";
    if (cultureInfo.Name != null)
    {
        // We only need to look at the first two characters to determine language
        language = cultureInfo.Name.Substring(0, 2);
    }
    bool defaultLanguage = false;

    // Filter languages such that only supported languages are loadable,
    // and any other defaults to the default/neutral language.
    switch (language)
    {
        case "da":
            break;

        default:
            defaultLanguage = true;
            break;
    }

    // Construct the URI
    string uri;
    if (defaultLanguage)
    {
        uri = basePath + "Localization.xaml";
    }
    else
    {
        uri = basePath + "Localization." + language + ".xaml";
    }

    // Load new dictionary
    dict.Source = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
    dictionary.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
}
```

This also works well to change language at runtime.

Please comment any questions so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first stage is to *unload* the current language resource dictionary, otherwise you're going to have loads of merged resource dictionaries which don't do anything.

It'd be a good idea to place all of your language files in one folder, like so:

[image: Language files]

Now, consider the following method:

```
public static void ReplaceLanguage(Uri source)
    {
        //The name of the folder where the languages are contained (could be a parameter)
        string folder = "languages";

        if (source == null)
            return;

        ResourceDictionary dictionary;

        try
        {
            dictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(source);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //resource file doesn't exist.
            return;
        }

        //Remove current resource from the merged dictionaries
        var currentResource = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Source != null && x.Source.ToString().Contains(folder));

        if (currentResource != null)
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(currentResource);

        //Add the new resource to the dictionary
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
    }
```

What this method does is:

1. Loads the resource dictionary from a URI source.
2. Finds and removes the current language dictionary based on the **folder name** that it is contained within.
3. Adds the new dictionary to the merged dictionaries list.

To get the Uri for the language file, you could do something like this:

```
Uri languagePath = new Uri(string.Format("/YourAppNamespace;component/resources/languages/{0}.xaml", language), UriKind.Relative);
```

*The above code assumes that your language files are named like **de.xaml** or **en.xaml**.*

All you need to do once you have the Uri, is call the **ReplaceLanguage** method.

Comment: This is actually pretty close to what I ended up doing. See my answer in a moment.